# when PHP include is used toogle button doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to built a basic website.
Βelow I have the nav.html document where I have designed a basic dropdown menu. When I open the nav.html with the browser the toggle button works fine, when I click on it,dropdown menu collapses and
when I click on it again drop-down disappears.
The problem appears when I include nav.html in a home.php file.
When I click on the toggle button, dropdown-menu collapses, but when I click on it again dropdown-menu remains open and doesn't disappear.

```
<html>

    <head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.7/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.7/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Popper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    </style>

    </head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-lignt">

         <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsingNavbar2">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon my-toggler"></span>

        </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="collapsingNavbar2">


        <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">

            <li class="nav-item active">

                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>

            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">

                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>

            </li>

        </ul>

    </div>

</nav>

</body>

</html>
```

**home.php**

```
<html>

<title>Home</title>

<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.7/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.7/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<style>

</style>

</head>


<body>

<?php include('./nav.html'); ?>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are including HTML in HTML and this is not supported. As you are including nav.html into home.php, you want to remove tags body, html and completly head.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-lignt">

         <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsingNavbar2">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon my-toggler"></span>

        </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="collapsingNavbar2">


        <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">

            <li class="nav-item active">

                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>

            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">

                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>

            </li>

        </ul>

    </div>

</nav>
```

PHP and HTML are completly different languages. With PHP you are generating HTML content. You are not including "the result" of nav.html, but the code.